# Вопрос по активной ссылке меню

Tags: django

Всем доброго времени суток. Может кто помочь пожалуйста, а то всю голову уже сломал за несколько дней. Вообщем есть следующий фрагмент кода:

main.html

```
<ul id="menu">
        {% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}
            <ul>
                <li class="{% if url_name == 'main' %}active{% endif %}">
                    main
                </li>
                <li class="{% if url_name == 'news_index' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a href="{% url 'news_index' %}">news</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        {% endwith %}
    </ul>
```

Первый элемент списка подсвечивается, когда становится активным при нажатии, второй элемент, в который добавлена ссылка не подсвечивается почему то. Может кто пожалуйста объяснить, что я неправильно делаю? Request в settings.py подключен. Если вместо url_name использовать request.path история повторяется.

Вот такие стили пробовал:

```
li.active a:active {
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

.active a:active {
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

li .active a:active {
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

.active {
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

a.active {
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

a .active {
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

.active a {
background-color: #0000FF;
color: green;
}

#menu .active a{
background-color: #FF0000;
color: green;
}

li.active a {
background-color: #0000FF;
color: green;
}

#menu li.active a {
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}

.active a:active {
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}

li.active a{
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}

#menu .active a{
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}

#leftmenu .menu .active a{
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}

#menu a li:hover, .active {
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}

#menu li.active a{
color: greenyellow;
background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Вообщем из пушки по воробьям, но так я не понял почему они не срабатывают... Но без тега `<a>` все срабатывает.

Comment: Так нажмите F12 в хроме, увидите исходник Вашего меню. Похоже на то, что не выполняется условие if url_name == 'news_index', и у Вас получается <li class=""> на выходе. Проверьте.

Comment: У Вас в CSS active прописан, как "подсветка" , наверное?

Comment: Я бы не искушал судьбу, и написал бы так: <li {% if url_name == 'news_index' %} class="active" {% endif %}>

Comment: Посмотрел в firebug исходники меню условие срабатывает, не срабатывают почему то стили. Сейчас отредактирую сообщение и выложу, что писал в стилях.

Comment: Так у href свой стиль наверное? :) Может проблема в этом? В Css не очень силён, но скорее всего дело именно в CSS. В chrome в инструментах разработчика можно посмотреть, какие стили и откуда унаследованы для конкретного элемента. Я бы с этой стороны заходил.

Comment: стили прописываются и работают вот так active a {...} , но что странно я прописал ради интереса у класса active паддинг и увеличил размер шрифта и они отработали, а измения цвета текста и фона не отрабатывают почему то и в консоли вываливается это "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0. Но как я понял 304 код состояния это ничего страшного, но в чем проблема я так и не понимаю пока что

Comment: 304 это закэшировано :) Очистите кэш браузера. А еще можно указать перед функцией в view @nevercache. Теоретически CSS может не обновляться из за этого очень долго

Comment: Вообщем всех благодарю за помощь, нашел в чем проблема была. Проблема была в стилях. До этого поставил стили совпадающими с фоном страницы и в классе active поставил другие, но они не переопределились. Как то так своими словами). Прошу прощения за свою невнимательность.